# Store the LINQ query result as JSON object and passing to javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I have a query which i added to a list. Now I need to use it in the javascript.It is being done in ASP.NET 3.5. So, I need to send it as a JSON object. This is what I've done:(I'm not sure if this is correct way of getting a JSON object. Correct me if i'm wrong.

```
    List<NCDCPoint> dupli = (from n in CDC.NCDCPoints
                             where n.EVENT_TYPE_ID == et
                             where n.BeginDate == b
                             where n.EndDate == e
                             select n).ToList<NCDCPoint>();
  System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer =
 new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
   string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(dupli); 





}
```

This is how my jquery looks

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST", url: "Data.aspx/CheckInsertRecord",
            data: "{EventType:'" + eventtype + "',BeginDate:'" + begindate + "'," +
                   "EndDate:'" + enddate+"' }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
            if(msg.d == "true")
        {
        Showduplicate();
        }
            }
        });
```

So, kindly let me know what I need to do next? One more thing is I already return true or false back to the $.ajax{} in aspx page. So how am is supposed to send JSON object?

Comment: -1, What's your framework? Where is this code being called? where do you already return true/false? What does your jQuery call look like? What does the "action" or ajax method on the server look like? You need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just getting started out then you're best off using ASP.NET MVC from the outset, it's much better than traditional ASP.NET Web Forms.  When you do that you want to create an action method that returns a `JsonResult`.  Here's a good article to get you started.

http://msmvps.com/blogs/shahed/archive/2009/08/23/asp-net-asp-net-mvc-tips-json-handler-aspx-template-asynchronous-jquery-treeview-with-ashx-generic-handler-and-many-more.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to return `List<NCDCPoint>` and declare the return type as json:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json]
public static List<NCDCPoint> CheckInsertRecord(String EventType, String BeginDate, String EndDate)
{
    NCDCPoint ncdc = new NCDCPoint();
    CEOSurveyDataContext CDC = new CEOSurveyDataContext();
    int et = Convert.ToInt32(EventType);


    DateTime b = Convert.ToDateTime(BeginDate);
   DateTime e = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate);

        bool query = ( from n in CDC.NCDCPoints
                      where n.EVENT_TYPE_ID == et
                      where n.BeginDate == b
                      where n.EndDate == e
                      select n).Count()>0;

    return = (from n in CDC.NCDCPoints
                             where n.EVENT_TYPE_ID == et
                             where n.BeginDate == b
                             where n.EndDate == e
                             select n).ToList<NCDCPoint>();
}
```

Comment: Hey can i send the "true or false" and JSON object at the same time...Or else I need to declare a seperate method for that

Comment: Hey.. when i tried to use an alert(msg.d).. I get nothing... actually its not even displaying the alert.

Answer (score 0):

You can serailize the Object using [`JavascriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) and send it.

```
var dupli= from n in CDC.NCDCPoints
                         where n.EVENT_TYPE_ID == et
                         where n.BeginDate == b
                         where n.EndDate == e
                         select n;

return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dupli);
```

And in the succes callback of jquery ajax.

```
...
success:function(msg){
var data = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
//And you get your object
}
```

Comment: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'aspnet_User'.  This is the error I'm getting when I updated the code.